# Java Pattern REGEX Where Not Matching

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use the Java Pattern and Matcher to apply input checks. I have it working in a really basic format which I am happy with so far. It applies a REGEX to an argument and then loops through the matching characters.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class RegexUtil {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String    argument;
      Pattern   pattern;
      Matcher   matcher;

      argument = "#a1^b2";
      pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|\\s");
      matcher = pattern.matcher(argument);

      // find all matching characters
      while(matcher.find()) {
         System.out.println(matcher.group());
      }

   }

}
```

This is fine for extracting all the good characters, I get the output

```
a
1
b
2
```

Now I wanted to know if it's possible to do the same for any characters that don't match the REGEX so I get the output

```
#
^
```

Or better yet loop through it and get TRUE or FALSE flags for each index of the argument

```
false
true
true
false
true
true
```

I only know how to loop through with matcher.find(), any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` will give you all characters not matching the range so: # ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add a `|(.)` alternative to your pattern (to match any char but a line break char) and check if Group 1 matched upon each match. If yes, output *false*, else, output *true*:

```
String argument = "#a1^b2";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|\\s|(.)"); // or "[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]|(.)"
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(argument);

while(matcher.find()) {                           // find all matching characters
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) == null);
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/tGbefs), output:

```
false
true
true
false
true
true
```

Note you do not need to use a `Pattern.DOTALL` here, because `\s` in your "whitelist" part of the pattern matches line breaks.

Comment: Check condition to print boolean can be simplified as basic `while (matcher.find()) {   System.out.println(matcher.group(1) == null); }`

Comment: @azro Yes, I just thought that a custom string might be necessary, if true or false are the only values needed then sure.

Comment: I like this answer a lot but I have a question about the group, if I create two groups "([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|\\s)|(.)" for clarity, why does matcher.group(2) not give me every character in the loop?

Comment: @Trent Because Group 1 will hold them. The regex is basically tokenizing a string into 2  types of chars, those you want to be labelled as *true* and those that must be *false*.

Comment: Ok, so anything that matches for group 1 can't match twice and won't match in group 2 as well?

Comment: @Trent Sorry, I do not get you. If you just want to print the match print it with `matcher.group(0)`.

Comment: It's ok, I'm to tinker a bit but this answer is perfect for what I need, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply removing all matching chars from your string, so you get only the non matching ones back:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class RegexUtil {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String    argument;
      Pattern   pattern;
      Matcher   matcher;

      argument = "#a1^b2";
      pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|\\s");
      matcher = pattern.matcher(argument);

      // find all matching characters
      while(matcher.find()) {
         System.out.println(matcher.group());
         argument = argument.replace(matcher.group(), "");
      }

      System.out.println("argument: " + argument);

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over each `char` of the `String` and check one by one :

```
//for-each loop, shorter way
for (char c : argument.toCharArray()){
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher(c + "").matches());
}
```

or

```
//classic for-i loop, with details
for (int i = 0; i < argument.length(); i++) {
    String charAtI = argument.charAt(i) + "";
    boolean doesMatch = pattern.matcher(charAtI).matches();
    System.out.println(doesMatch);
}
```

---

Also, when you don't require it, you can do declaration and give a value at same time :

```
String argument = "#a1^b2";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|\\s");
```

Answer (score 0):

Track positions, and for each match, print the characters between last match and current match.

```
int pos = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = pos; i < matcher.start(); i++) {
        System.out.println(argument.charAt(i));
    }
    pos = matcher.end();
}
// Print any trailing characters after last match.
for (int i = pos; i < argument.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(argument.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is

```
    String  argument;
    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;

    argument = "#a1^b2";
    List<String> charList = Arrays.asList(argument.split(""));
    pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|\\s");
    matcher = pattern.matcher(argument);
    ArrayList<String> unmatchedCharList = new ArrayList<>();
    // find all matching
    while(matcher.find()) {
        unmatchedCharList.add(matcher.group());
    }
    for(String charr : charList)
    {
        System.out.println(unmatchedCharList.contains(charr ));
    }
```

Output

false
true
true
false
true
true